# PlayFramework get Routes configuration upon module.configure

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, guice

For my Play 2.5 project I'm working on a module which uses annotations to configure security related stuff. 
During the configure phase of my custom guice module I have all the annotated methods and the corresponding field values. So no problems there.

Now I have to map these values to a path (e.g. /album/{:id} as configured in the routes file).

Does anybody know how to map the given controller method (Application.getAlbum() ) to the path configured in the routes file? 
(Other than me loading the routes file myself and parsing it?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the route path from the request tags.

In Java:

```
requestHeader.tags().get(Router.Tags.ROUTE_PATTERN)
```

(see [DeadboltRoutePathFilter.java](https://github.com/schaloner/deadbolt-2-java/blob/master/code/app/be/objectify/deadbolt/java/filters/DeadboltRoutePathFilter.java#L64) for example)

In Scala:

```
requestHeader.tags(Tags.RoutePattern)
```

(see [DeadboltRoutePathFilter.scala](https://github.com/schaloner/deadbolt-2-scala/blob/master/code/app/be/objectify/deadbolt/scala/filters/DeadboltRoutePathFilter.scala#L47) for example)

Comment: Thanks for your reponse!
But, what you are referring to is within the Action. There I know you can access it using the ctx() and request object. 
I'm actually referring to the init phase of the application where the modules get started (AbstractModule.configure()). 
In my Module I need to map certain annotation values to the paths configured in the routes file.

Comment: When I looked at this a while ago, the closest I could find in the API was https://playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/api/java/play/routing/Router.html#documentation-- but even then you're not getting route objects. That's why my implementation in Deadbolt matches the path on a per-request basis.